# How to make it so when the view loads, it displays something based on the value of an NSInteger?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I am making a quiz app that displays a saying at the end of the quiz based on the value of the NSInteger myScore. How would I code this? Any help would be helpful 'haha'. Thanks!

Comment: How are you planning to display the string? UILabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array that stores your witty remarks, and calculate an array index out of the score. Something like this:

```
NSArray *wittyNotes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       NSLocalizedString(@"Foo", nil),          // 0 - 99
                       NSLocalizedString(@"Bar", nil),          // 100 - 199
                       NSLocalizedString(@"Baz", nil),          // 200 - 299
                       NSLocalizedString(@"Over 9000", nil),    // 300 - ...
                       nil];
NSInteger index = myScore / 100;
if (index >= [wittyNotes count]) {
    index = [wittyNotes count] - 1;
}
NSString *wittyNote = [wittyNotes objectAtIndex:index];
```

Depending on your wishes you could make the myScore-to-index calculation more complicated.