# how to make it so when a view loads, it does something?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I am making a quiz app, and I wanted it to have a saying at the end of the quiz. This saying is supposed to change based on an NSInteger (myScore). How would I code this? Any help would be helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: EDIT                PLEASE READ                                        The last question of the quiz is a different xib than the xib that will display the saying. Note: Each time that a question is answered, it adds to the myScore integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make it so when the view loads, it displays something based on the value of an NSInteger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987906/how-to-make-it-so-when-the-view-loads-it-displays-something-based-on-the-value-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to create a UILabel based on an NSInteger:

```
NSInteger yourInteger;
UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[aLabel setText:@"Score %d", yourInteger];
[aLabel setBackgroundcolor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[aLabel setOpaque:NO];
[[self view] addSubview:aLabel];
```

actually %d is replaced with your integer

Comment: and i don't see anything about the variable. Its supposed to display something like for example, if they scored 50 points, i want it to say good job! or something like that.

Comment: you put this into YourViewController.m in viewDidLoad, or viewWillAppear if your game has play again feature,

Comment: for the saying you can write this after the Declaration of uilabel : if (yourInteger > 50){ [aLabel setText:@"Good job, you scored over %d", 50]}, and remove the [aLabel setText:@"Score %d", yourScore] line